# SIP CANCEL Request

Tags: sip

Why does SIP CANCEL method need same CSeq number and branch id as INVITE. To match CANCEL with corresponding INVITE branch id is enough. Since it is a long value it is sufficient enough to identify the transaction. Then why CANCEL cseq has same value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is for compliance with previous specification, ie: [rfc2543](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2543.txt). In this old specification, branch parameter wasn't used. Instead, rq-uri, to-tag, call-id, cseq and top-via was checked.

To maintain compatibility with [rfc2543](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2543.txt), the new specfication requires the usage of a branch starting with magic cookie ("z9hG4bK") but still requires the old way.

To match an INVITE, a CANCEL should follow the rules defined in Section 17.2.3 of [rfc3261](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3261.txt) (Matching Requests to Server Transactions)

```
If the branch parameter in the top Via header field is not present,
or does not contain the magic cookie, the following procedures are
used.  These exist to handle backwards compatibility with RFC 2543
compliant implementations.

The INVITE request matches a transaction if the Request-URI, To tag,
From tag, Call-ID, CSeq, and top Via header field match those of the
INVITE request which created the transaction.
```

Comment: You don't have to! rfc3261 provides all informations you need to be compliant with rfc2543...